# Visual Studio conflicts with Ionic Builds

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

If Visual Studio 2015 Community is installed with the Ionic/Cordova add ons. Will it conflict with my existing setup used for Ionic builds?

It states on the VS site that Apache Ant, Java SDK,  Android SDK, NodeJS are installed by VS as part of the package. Will these duplicate or conflict with my existing setup where I manually installed Java, Android SDK and Ant/Node?

What are the advantages of using Visual Studio 2015 over a manual install?

Answer (score 0):

No it should not conflict with your current setup, [you can choose what VS will install in the installation routine](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#choose).

If you decide to use your previously installed tools, just deselect them while installing. Afterwards you can configure your toolset under Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova like in the following screenshot (it's german but you should get the idea).
[image: Options dialog]

Advantages of using a preconfigured setup? Well they should work out of the box and it might be easier to get help/support if you broke anything.

Disadvantages are the old versions of the installed JDK for example. TACO ships with JDK 1.7.0_55 if I remember right, which is pretty old and maybe even vulnerable?!

Recommendation: Take the time and configure your tools on your own or change the preinstalled tools to meet your needs if you're going to use VS frequently. If you're just messing around or trying things out, stick with the preinstalled configuration.